# Is Wanda Astral Projecting?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision, scarlet-witch

In the last post credit in *WandaVision*, why are there 2 Wandas? Is she astral projecting like in *Doctor Strange*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Jac Schaeffer, the showrunner for *WandaVision*, has confirmed that Wanda was astral projecting in that scene.

> "I love the duality of it. I love the real Wanda, sitting on her porch, making a cup of tea, doing her ruminating and reflecting," Schaeffer says. "And the super-lady in the back room who is astral-projecting and functioning at a level that we have yet to understand. I love that."
>
> <sub>[ComicBookMovie.com, WANDAVISION Showrunner Explains The Show's Ending; Director Confirms There Was Once Plans For An Episode 10](https://www.comicbookmovie.com/tv/marvel/wandavision/wandavision-showrunner-explains-the-shows-ending-director-confirms-there-was-once-plans-for-an-episode-10-a183021#gs.3fg8rv)</sub>

Comment: Wait so why doesn't she go limp as the Dr. Strange characters do? just because she's super powerful? (Scarlet Witch and all)

Comment: @HahemLovesYou It's been a while since I've watched Doctor Strange. However, when the Ancient One does it to Strange that's not him controlling it and he's untrained at that point. Wanda, however, is more powerful than the Sorcerer Supreme and she is doing it under her control.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh0f7LWcF-o got to 2:00

Comment: Strange only goes limp the first time the Ancient One forces it on him. Later, we see him doing it while sleeping (to maximize study time) or when unconcsious in the hospital @HahemLovesYou